# SQLExecDirect returns SQL_ERROR after SELECT query but works fine when executed alone

Tags: c++, sql, c, sql-server

I am testing SQL Server on C++ and got this error:

- When I execute "SELECT" query alone, it works fine
  [SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL1Yo.png)
- When I execute "UPDATE" query alone, it also works fine
  [UPDATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CG1k.png)
- But when I execute any queries after my "SELECT" query, I got SQL_ERROR
  [SELECT THEN UPDATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKcVP.png)

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
using namespace std;

#define SQL_RESULT_LEN 240
#define SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN 1000

int main() {
    string username, password;
    int mode;

    string query;
    wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    wstring wstr;

    SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];

    sqlConnHandle = NULL;
    sqlStmtHandle = NULL;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, 
    (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
        goto COMPLETED;
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;

    cout << "Attempting connection to SQL Server...";
    cout << "\n";

    switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost, 
        1433;DATABASE=login;UID=sa;PWD=beth12po;",
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
    {
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    case SQL_ERROR:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlConnHandle, &sqlStmtHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;

    cout << "Enter username: ";
    getline(cin, username);
    cout << "Enter password: ";
    getline(cin, password);

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Logging in...";
    cout << "\n";

    query = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE username='" + username + "';";
    wstr = converter.from_bytes(query);
    wcout << wstr << endl;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)wstr.c_str(), SQL_NTS)) {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
    }

    query = "UPDATE Account SET status = 1 WHERE username='" + username + "';";
    wstr = converter.from_bytes(query);
    wcout << wstr << endl;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)wstr.c_str(), SQL_NTS)) {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
    }

COMPLETED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlStmtHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlEnvHandle);

    cout << "\nPress any key to exit...";
    getchar();
}
```

This is my Database:
[Design DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq9AA.png)
[Data DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHDA3.png)

Anyone knows how SQLEXECDIRECT works and why it returns error after "SELECT" query? I'm new to SQL Server

Comment: Try calling `SQLCloseCursor` between the two `SQLExecDirect`. My guess is, after the `SELECT` statement, the handle is in a state where it expects you to actually read the resultset (with `SQLFetch` or similar), and is not ready to execute another statement. I can't help but wonder though - what's the point of running a `SELECT` statement if you aren't going to read the results?

Comment: FYI, I **strongly** suggest you research parametrised statements; your code has a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: Also, a column called `password` with the data type `nvarchar(50)` suggests you are storing plain text password; another fatal flaw.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My original code has SQLFetch() to get password and active Status